# modify shell script to delete folders as well as files

Tags: bash, shell, find, rm

My shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
    echo "$0 : Not enough argument supplied. 2 Arguments needed."
    echo "Argument 1: -d for debug (lists files it will remove) or -e for execution."
    echo "Followed by some path to remove files from. (path of where to look) "
    exit 1
fi

if test $1 == '-d'
then
    find $2 -mmin +60 -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
elif test $1 == '-e'
then
    find $2 -mmin +60 -type f -exec rm -rf {} \;
fi
```

Basically this will find files in a given directory provided as second argument and either list (-d for argument 1) or remove (-e for argument 1) files modified >60 minutes ago.

How can I rework this to also remove folders ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove `-type f`
- changing `ls -l` to `ls -ld`

Change 1 will list everything and not just files. This includes links as well. If you are not fine with listing/deleting anything other than files and directories then you need to separately list/delete files and directories as:

```
if test $1 == '-d'
then
    find $2 -mmin +60 -type f -exec ls -ld {} \;
    find $2 -mmin +60 -type d -exec ls -ld {} \;
elif test $1 == '-e'
then
    find $2 -mmin +60 -type f -exec rm -rf {} \;
    find $2 -mmin +60 -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
fi
```

Change 2 is needed as `ls -l` on a directory will list the files in the directories.

Comment: You can combine the `-types`: `find $2 -mmin +60 \( -type f -o -type d \) -exec ls -ld {} \;`

Comment: Warning: this may not do what you want: directories (including $2 itself) will be deleted even if they have active files/subdirs in them, if the directory itself has not been modified in the last hour.  Avoiding this problem is ... more complicated, especially in dry run mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
    echo "$0 : Not enough argument supplied. 2 Arguments needed."
    echo "Argument 1: -d for debug (lists files it will remove) or -e for execution."
    echo "Followed by some path to remove files from. (path of where to look) "
    exit 1
fi

if test $1 == '-d'
then
    find $2 -mmin +60 -type d -exec ls -l {} \;
    find $2 -mmin +60 -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
elif test $1 == '-e'
then
    find $2 -mmin +60 -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
    find $2 -mmin +60 -type f -exec rm -rf {} \;
fi
```

That should work for you.